# How do I make a Maven location to be non-standard by default for each new IntelliJ IDEA project?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When I add a new project in IntelliJ IDEA, by default the Maven location is the bundled Maven. But I need a specific location. How can I set up it on the IDE level to be always selected in the custom location by default?

[image: A]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245365). Please follow it for updates.